# Trying to send a message with Yowsup Python

Tags: python

I get "IndentationError: unexpected indent" from this code. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
from yowsup.layers.interface                           import YowInterfaceLayer, ProtocolEntityCallback
from yowsup.layers.protocol_messages.protocolentities  import TextMessageProtocolEntity
from yowsup.common.tools import Jid

class EchoLayer(YowInterfaceLayer):

    @ProtocolEntityCallback("message")
    def onMessage(self, messageProtocolEntity):

        if messageProtocolEntity.getType() == 'text':
            self.onTextMessage(messageProtocolEntity)
         
         reply = 1
         messageEntity = TextMessageProtocolEntity(reply,to = messageProtocolEntity.getFrom())
self.toLower(messageEntity)
         
        self.toLower(messageProtocolEntity.forward(messageProtocolEntity.getFrom()))
        self.toLower(messageProtocolEntity.ack())
        self.toLower(messageProtocolEntity.ack(True))


    @ProtocolEntityCallback("receipt")
    def onReceipt(self, entity):
        self.toLower(entity.ack())

    def onTextMessage(self,messageProtocolEntity):
        # just print info
        print("Echoing %s to %s" % (messageProtocolEntity.getBody(), messageProtocolEntity.getFrom(False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> IndentationError: unexpected indent

This is a common kind of problem every pythoner has hit with. your code has some extra space or any tab is used.so basically you have to check every line and manually remove the excess gaps(shortcuts) and replace them with spaces insted.

Answer (score 0):

The `Unexpected indent` error message will always tell you what line the problem is detected on.

In your case, it's obviously due to the fact that the `if` and `reply` lines don't match up.